# Google App Engine Check Success of backup programmatically

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am taking the backup of datastore , using Taskqueues. I want to check whether the backup has completed successfully or not. I can check the end of the backup job by checking the taskqueue, but how can i check whether the backup was successful or it failed due to some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not currently a well-supported way to do this.

However, with the disclaimer that this is likely to break at some point in the future, as it depends on internal implementation details, You can fetch the relevant _AE_Backup_Information and _AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation entities from your datastore and inspect them for information regarding the backup. In particular, the _AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation has fields active_jobs, completed_jobs, and status.